# Как получить ответ на POST запрос (python,Django)

Tags: python, django

Всем привет, начал изучать Django, затык на базе, как получить, проверить и ответить на POST запрос. То есть я создал поле answer куда пользователь пишет свой ответ и нажимает кнопку сохранить, как проверить правильность данных введенных пользователем?

```
#models.py

from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField() # Вопрос
    answer = models.IntegerField() # Правильный ответ

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Result(models.Model):
    test = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    result = models.BooleanField(default=False) # результат
```

```
    #views.py
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from .models import Question
    from .forms import QuestionForm
    
    def index(request):
        questions = Question.objects.all()
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save
                
        return render(request,'quiz/index.html',{'questions':questions,'form':form})
```

```
#forms.py
from django import forms

from .models import Question

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ("answer",)

#index.html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Вопрос</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for question in questions %}
            {{ question }}
            <form method="POST" class="post-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `request.POST` вернёт Вам словарь с данными POST-запроса.

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете получить данные из поля через словарь `cleaned_data`:

```
def index(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            answer = form.cleaned_data['answer']
```

[Документация](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#field-data)